# Prove that there exist a diagonalizable operator $D$ and a nilpotent operator $N$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization, nilpotence

Let $\mathbb V$ be an $n$ dimensional complex vector space. If $T \in L(V,V),$ prove that there exists a diagonalizable operator $D$ and a nilpotent operator $N$ such that $T = D + N$  and $DN = ND$
and show that these mappings are uniquely determined.

**Attempt:** If $V$ be a vector space with $\dim V=n$, Then, the  "kernel lemma" states that 
$$V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \ker (T- \lambda_i \mathrm{I})^{n}$$
and each of the subspaces $G(\lambda_i,T) = \ker (T- \lambda_i \mathrm{I})^{n}$ is invariant under $T$.

Now on each $G(\lambda_i,T)$, we have have $T = \lambda_i \mathrm{I}+ (T - \lambda_i \mathrm{I})$ and the second term is nilpotent.

For a vector $v$ we can write it as $v=v_1+...+v_n$ with $v_i \in G(λ_i,T).$ Then $Nv=∑_iNv_i=∑_i(T−λ_iI)|_{G(λi,T)}v_i$

> This produces a sum of nilpotent operators. The sum of nilpotent operators might not be nilpotent. So,How do I use this to define a general $T$? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You already have what you need defined on each $G(\lambda_i,T)$. Put them together, define $D=\bigoplus_i\lambda_iI|_{G(\lambda_i,T)}$ and $N=\bigoplus_i(T-\lambda_iI)|_{G(\lambda_i,T)}$.

Comment: @topeik I am sorry. If we define $N$ as the direct sum of individual operators, how do we define $Nv$ for some vector $v$? Thanks

Comment: The direct sum of operators is defined by their actions on each factor. For a vector $v$ write it as $v=v_1+...+v_n$ with $v_i\in G(\lambda_i,T)$. Then $Nv=\sum_i Nv_i=\sum_i (T-\lambda_iI)|_{G(\lambda_i,T)}v_i$.

Comment: @topeik this produces a sum of nilpotent operators. The sum of nilpotent operators might not be nilpotent.